# Create other collision shapes

Tags: collision

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

How could I add more fancy shapes for collision, other than the simple provided primitives : box, sphere and cylinder. I know this would decrease performance, but I definitely have to do so.

Thanks!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4501/create-other-collision-shapes/) by [mowahed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/440/mowahed/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Please see the [tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/beginner/mesh_import)

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mowahed](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/440/mowahed/) on 2013-09-26**:
Thank you.